# Where I can put the .stop() in this animite

Tags: jquery-selectors

I made the mouse hover animate, when I move the mouse over the link it will show the image and when I move the mouse to another link the previous image have to disappear and show another image that belong to another link.

```
        <style>
         .imgHover {
         display: inline;
         position: relative;
         }
       .hover {
       display: none;
        position: absolute;

        z-index: 2;
        }
      </style>



 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
     $(".imgHover").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).children("img").fadeTo(200, 0.85).end().children(".hover").fadeIn(100);
    },
    function() {
        $(this).children("img").fadeTo(200, 1).end().children(".hover").fadeOut(100)();
    });
    });</script>


   <a class="imgHover" href="htpp://google.com">Text Link 1
   <img class="hover" src="image_link1.jpg" alt=""></a>


   <a class="imgHover" href="htpp://google.com">Text Link 2
   <img class="hover" src="image_link2.jpg" alt=""></a>
```

///////////////////////////////////
Can I move the code link this and when I mouse hover Text Link 1 the script select the image 1... Please help.

```
   <div id="imageshow">
  <img class="hover" src="image_link1.jpg" alt="">
 <img class="hover" src="image_link2.jpg" alt="">
  </div>


     <div id="link">
    <a class="imgHover" href="htpp://google.com">Text Link 1   </a>
    <a class="imgHover" href="htpp://google.com">Text Link 2   </a>

   </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put it before the first fade:

```
$(".imgHover").hover(
function() {
    $(this).children("img").stop().fadeTo(200, 0.85).end().children(".hover").fadeIn(100);
},
function() {
    $(this).children("img").stop().fadeTo(200, 1).end().children(".hover").fadeOut(100)();
});
```

Comment: Can I move the code link this and when I mouse hover Text Link 1 the script select the image 1... Please help.

<div id="imageshow">
<img class="hover" src="image_link1.jpg" alt="">
<img class="hover" src="image_link2.jpg" alt="">
</div>


<div id="link">
<a class="imgHover" href="htpp://google.com">Text Link 1   </a>
 <a class="imgHover" href="htpp://google.com">Text Link 2   </a>

</div>

Comment: Try this:     $(".imgHover").each(
function(index) {
 $("link").children("a").fadeTo(200, 0.85);
 $("link").children("a").eq(index).stop().end().children(".hover").fadeTo("normal", 1);

});

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
     $(".imgHover").hover(
    function() {
        $(".imgHover img, .imgHover img .hover").stop();
        $(this).children("img").fadeTo(200, 0.85).end().children(".hover").fadeIn(100);
    },
    function() {
        $(".imgHover img, .imgHover img .hover").stop();
        $(this).children("img").fadeTo(200, 1).end().children(".hover").fadeOut(100)();
    });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Can I move the code link this and when I mouse hover Text Link 1 the script select the image 1... Please help.

    <div id="imageshow">
    <img class="hover" src="image_link1.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="hover" src="image_link2.jpg" alt="">
   </div>


  <div id="link">
   <a class="imgHover" href="htpp://google.com">Text Link 1   </a>
   <a class="imgHover" href="htpp://google.com">Text Link 2   </a>

   </div>

Comment: Can u please be more specific? I have no idea what you want.

Comment: Can you see the Edit Please, i don't know how to put the code in the Add Comment